# Prove that there is no n, such 289 divides $(n-5)(n-12)+51$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$289$ = $17^2$ , and
$17 | 51 $ so $17 | (n-5)(n+12) + 51 $ iff
$17|(n-5)(n+12)$. With the prime property, 
$ 17 |(n-5)$ or $(n+12)$ Both happens, when n is congruent to $5$ mod $7$. So if $17| (n-5)(n-12)+51 $ then $17^2 |(n-5)(n-12)  $ ,. How can I finish the proof?

Comment: Sorry for these elementary questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are done: $17^2$ divides $(n-5)(n+12)$ but does not divide $51$ hence it does not divide the sum of the two.

Comment: So there is no such case like if 17 doesnt divide (n-5)(n+12) , but 17^2 divides (n-5)(n+12) +51? So 17|(n-5)(n+12) + 51 is a must needed condition?

Comment: If $17$ does not divide $(x-5)(x+12)$, then $17$ does not divide $(x-5)(x+12)+51$. Thus also $17^2$ does not divide it.

Comment: In general, if $nm|k$ then $n|k$.

Comment: I see now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $289|(n-5)(n-12)$ and $289|(n-5)(n-12)+51$, then $289|51$, a contradiction.